# PHP software center (for providing software downloads in an intranet)

Tags: gratis, web-apps, php

I am looking for a software center program based in PHP. It should be able to host files for downloading, have descriptions, and (preferably) have custom fields.

This is going to be used in a web portal to provide free software downloads to users of an intranet.

The software NEEDS to be free, and preferably open source.

Answer (score -1):

The magic search term that you are looking for is CMS - *Content Management System*. There are a large number available, in various languages including PHP, such as:

[Quick.Cms](http://opensolution.org/cms-system-quick-cms.html)

Comment: And how does "such as" fit the requirements? Your answer leaves that open, and thus is rather a comment ;) CMS in general is not primarily targeted at "download center for software", so that would be a bit broad – plus might be killing flies using atomics. Might not apply to the product you mentioned, but you didn't explain ;)

Comment: I currently use a CMS, but it's a big pain to create a page for EACH PROGRAM. I would like to have something that does it automatically. Meaning, I upload a program, add a title, add a description, and maybe add a serial key (corporate software). I do NOT want to create each page by hand.

Comment: This is what scripting is for!